# Drag and Drop with phonegap

Tags: html, drag

How is the drag and drop functionality implemented in PhoneGap?

Please tell me the available javascript functions or libraries for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your APP is based on HTML 5 instead of native implementation. Thus Jquery-Mobile-Drag-And-Drop might be a choice.
[Jquery-Mobile-Drag-And-Drop Plugin](http://www.jsplugins.com/Scripts/Plugins/View/Jquery-Mobile-Drag-And-Drop/)